# Spring Cloud Gateway setup multiple virtual hosts

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm on `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` (`Hoxton.SR5`) trying to support multiple hosts but not having luck.

I would like `http://en.portal.com/common` route to port `80` and `http://us.portal.com/common` route to port `81`.

```
- id: host_route_en
    uri: lb://127.0.0.1:80
    predicates:
    - Host=en.portal.com
    - Path=/common/**
  - id: host_route_us
    uri: lb://127.0.0.1:81
    predicates:
    - Host=us.portal.com
    - Path=/common/**
```

Could you guide how to achieve that.

Comment: you should use `http://` not `lb://`. The `lb` scheme is only used for service discovery and you're not using that.

Comment: @spencergibb - Yes, I'm using service discovery. Actually the uri is "lb://HOME" which is routed to port http://127.0.0.1:80

Comment: The registered port is what is used. What are the registered ports?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```yml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: host_route_en
        uri: http://127.0.0.1:80
        predicates:
        - Host=en.portal.com
        - Path=/common/**
      - id: host_route_us
        uri: http://127.0.0.1:81
        predicates:
        - Host=us.portal.com
        - Path=/common/**
```

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#shortcut-configuration

Comment: This is what I had in the config. I just coped part of it. sorry my mistake.